# Pagination : which page numbers to show?

Tags: pagination

On my blog I put the following links to show pagination (première and dernière mean first and last, respectively) :

[image]

But on the stackexchange sites the links are different :

[image]

Which is easier to understand, and is there another way to navigate between pages, an 'approved' way ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing that the SE pagination component has over yours is that it displays how many pages there are total.

This is something to consider, will the user get frustrated if he presses your "Last-link" and expects maybe page 15 but ends up on page 115?

Another UI feedback that your version lacks is indication of further pagination. At first I thought "9" was the last page in your pagination. It was actually from seeing that the first number in the pagination was "5" that I understood that there might be additional pages after 9, but the UI doesn't clearly communicate that. The use of "..." that SE utilizes is one intuitive way of communicating this.

Answer (score 2):

Just "Older Posts / Newer Posts" would be apt on blogs. I have seen people having a point of confusion between 'Next / Previous' wondering if the 'previous' pages is having new posts or old posts and similar for 'next'.

The pagination is only required if there are post in large numbers, say more than 500. Who will go through each pages? If one has to go in that way, shouldn't we be giving a search & filtering option?

Also read some notes by Jeff Atwood on pagination http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/the-end-of-pagination.html

Comment: +1: I just read that his morning and was thinking about posting a link to it in comments!